# NGRX - feature is not added to store's state

Tags: angular, redux, dependency-injection, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to implement an authorization functionality but I can't get the effects to work. The actions get dispatched but effects never trigger, after a lot of debugging I found that the state is actually not being added to the store.

I basically created an authentication module and inside it I register the feature to the store:

```
export const AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDED_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('providedConfig');

@NgModule()
export class AuthenticationModule {
  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.store.pipe(select(state => state))
      .subscribe(state => {
        console.log('Current store state - AUTHENTICATION MODULE:', state);
      });
  }

  static forRoot(config: AuthenticationConfig) {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthenticationModule,
      imports:[
        EffectsModule.forFeature(authenticationEffects),
        // I also tried doing forFeature(featurekey, reducer).
        StoreModule.forFeature(fromAuthentication.authenticationFeature),
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthenticationFacadeService,
        {
          provide: AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDED_CONFIG,
          useValue: config,
        },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this authenticationModule is then imported into my AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    AuthenticationModule.forRoot(authenticationConfig),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      stateKey: 'router'
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.store.pipe(select(state => state))
      .subscribe(state => {
        console.log('Current store state - APP MODULE:', state);
      });
  }
}
```

As you can see I added some loggers to each module's constructor. this is what they log:
[image]

As I understand the authorization feature key should appear on those logs, right?

I also checked on redux DevTools and my action is indeed being dispatched but effect never gets triggered:

[image]